# Dependency missing when running AzureML Estimator in docker environment

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

#### Scenario description

I'm trying to submit a training script to AzureML (want to use AmlCompute, but I'm starting/testing locally first, for debugging purposes).

The `train.py` script I have uses a custom package (`arcus.ml`) and I believe I have specified the right settings and dependencies, but still I get the error:

`User program failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcus.ml'`

#### Code and reproduction

This the python code I have:

```py
name='test'
script_params = {
    '--test-par': 0.2
}

est = Estimator(source_directory='./' + name,
                   script_params=script_params,
                   compute_target='local',
                   entry_script='train.py',
                   pip_requirements_file='requirements.txt',
                   conda_packages=['scikit-learn','tensorflow', 'keras'])

run = exp.submit(est)
print(run.get_portal_url())
```

This is the (fully simplified) train.py script in the `test`directory:

```py
from arcus.ml import dataframes as adf
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore, Experiment, Run

# get hold of the current run
run = Run.get_context()
ws = run.get_environment()

print('training finished')
```

And this is my requirements.txt file

```
arcus-azureml
arcus-ml
numpy
pandas
azureml-core
tqdm
joblib
scikit-learn
matplotlib
tensorflow
keras
```

#### Logs

In the logs file of the run, I can see this section, sot it seems the external module is being installed anyhow.

```
Collecting arcus-azureml
  Downloading arcus_azureml-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting arcus-ml
  Downloading arcus_ml-1.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 kB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error isn't necessarily about Azure ML. I think the error has to do w/ the difference b/w using a hyphen and a period in your package name. But I'm a python packaging newb. 
In a new conda environment on my laptop, I ran the following

```
> conda create -n arcus python=3.6 -y
> conda activate arcus
> pip install arcus-ml
> python
>>> from arcus.ml import dataframes as adf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcus'
```

When I look in the env's site packages folder, I didn't see the `arcus/ml` folder structure I was expecting. There's no arcus code there at all, only the `.dist-info` file

#### `~/opt/anaconda3/envs/arcus/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Anders!  It was indeed related to the actual release of the arcus package.  Good catch and apologies for my noob mistake...

Answer (score 2):

It could be there's an issue with arcus-ml 1.0.6 wheel installable, like Anders pointed out it doesn't seem to have any code. Could you try with earlier version arcus-ml==1.0.5 ?